# Include a qmake project in another qmake project

Tags: c++, qt, qmake

I have created an application in qt/c++

Browser/Browser.pro

To start the browser, I need an agent. I have created an agent and store it in the Browser folder

```
Browser/Browser.pro
        Browser.cpp
        main.cpp
        Agent/Agent.pro
        Agent/agent.cpp
```

When building the Browser, I'm generating an app but it's only build the browser.

I have added in Browser.pro the line below:

```
SUBDIRS += \
  Agent/Agent.pro

browser.depend = Agent/Agent.pro
```

My concerns is that I'm trying to build browser.app and automatically agent.app .
The goal after is to integrate the the agent.app generated in the resource of the browser.app

Any idea

Answer (score 2):

`SUBDIRS` variable is only interpreted in `TEMPLATE=subdirs` pro file.
Also, it does take only the directory name where to find your project, not the `.pro` itself.

You should create a directory for your `Browser` project and get this:

```
Browser/
       |-Browser.pro
       |-Browser/
                |-Browser.pro
                |- ...
       |-Agent/
              |-Agent.pro
              |- ...
```

And then your main project file will be like this:

Browser.pro:

```
    TEMPLATE = subdirs
    SUBDIRS = Agent Browser
    CONFIG += ordered
```

More information about subdirs : http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#subdirs